# FeedparserDict object doesn't have 'content' attribute

Tags: feedparser

I am trying to get familiar with the feedparser library, but I don't seem to be able to access the content attribute of entries in the feedparser object:

```
d = feedparser.parse('http://www.reddit.com/r/python/.rss')
post = d.entries[2]
post.content
```

the above code block gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\feedparser.py", line 414, in __getattr__
    return self.__getitem__(key)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\feedparser.py", line 375, in __getitem__
    return dict.__getitem__(self, key)
KeyError: 'content'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#87>", line 1, in <module>
    content = post.content[0].value
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\feedparser.py", line 416, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("object has no attribute '%s'" % key)
AttributeError: object has no attribute 'content'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do a print(post) and you will probably see that it doesn't have a content attribute.
RSS feeds do not guarantee that it will have one.